# flexbox makes content disappear

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm playing around with flexbox to get the hang of it but I am running into some issues. My goal is to have the window separated by four background colors where the first is just a header row and then the rest of the page is filled by 3 columns each a different background color. But for some reason if I write display: flex it doesn't show anything. Can someone explain to me how to get this desired effect?

```css
   .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.col-container {
  widows: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
}
.col-container:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}
.col-container:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
.col-container:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="col-container">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: don't forget to add the class names col-1, col-2 and col-3 to your markup

Comment: There are a couple typos in your code. 1) You have no `col-1`, `col-2` or `col-3` in your HTML...you just have `col`. 2) I'm guessing you want `flex-direction: row` as you want the columns next to each other and not stacked

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong this is what I have, and yes you are right it should be row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-container {
  widows: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col-1 {
  flex: 1 1 33.333%;
  background-color: green;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 1 1 33.333%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 1 1 33.333%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="col-container">
      <div class="col-1">ts</div>
      <div class="col-2">dtd</div>
      <div class="col-3">dt</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's what you needed to fix:

1. Set `flex-direction` to `row`. You most likely want the columns next to each other.
2. Add the classes to your HTML for the `col-1`, `col-2` and `col-3`.
3. You need content in those `col` classes, or you won't see anything anyway.

I set a `flex-basis` (the third parameter in the `flex` shorthand) to 33.333%. You don't necessarily need this, but it's nice to see how much space a particular element will fill or change it.

**EDIT** For the comments:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-container {
  widows: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.col-1 {
  flex: 1 1 33.333%;
  background-color: green;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 1 1 33.3333%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 1 1 33.3333%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="col-container">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Basically, you need to give the `col-container` a height. To achieve this, I used `vh` units in the `calc` statement. It subtracts your header height from the viewport height and gives the remainder. This also removes the necessity for filler content.

Comment: Thank you! But two questions, how do i get the colors to show without having any filler text, and how do I get the colors to take up the entirety of the remaining height in the browser?

Comment: I was just able to achieve this by giving all the indivual columns a height of 100vh, but i assume your solution is a lot better...thank you so much really appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, no need to give the columns the height, give it to the container and let flex-box do the work. Good luck!